# The differences between dependency tags

Tags: catkin, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to Robotic Operating System, so this can be fundamental question. When I was investigating dependency tags of `package.xml` file of my newly-created package, I faced two dependency tags that I could not resolve.

According to the researches that I made, if a file from the package A is required to build our newly-created package, then package A is specified in the dependency tags like this: `<build_depend> A </build_depend>`. This sounds senseful. However, I could not find out following dependency tags:

`<build_export_depend> </build_export_depend>`

`<exec_depend> </exec_depend>`

When I created my package, I used the following command:

`catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp`

These three packages are also specified in two tags mentioned above. Is there anyone who knows what these dependency tags mean ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313370/the-differences-between-dependency-tags/) by [gktg1514](https://answers.ros.org/users/37700/gktg1514/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2019-01-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [ROS wiki on catkin packages](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/package.xml):

> **Build Dependencies** specify which packages are needed to build this
> package. This is the case when any
> file from these packages is required
> at build time. This can be including
> headers from these packages at
> compilation time, linking against
> libraries from these packages or
> requiring any other resource at build
> time (especially when these packages
> are find_package()-ed in CMake). In a
> cross-compilation scenario build
> dependencies are for the targeted
> architecture.
>
> **Build Export Dependencies** specify which packages are needed to build
> libraries against this package. This
> is the case when you transitively
> include their headers in public
> headers in this package (especially
> when these packages are declared as
> (CATKIN_)DEPENDS in catkin_package()
> in CMake).
>
> **Execution Dependencies** specify which packages are needed to run code
> in this package. This is the case when
> you depend on shared libraries in this
> package (especially when these
> packages are declared as
> (CATKIN_)DEPENDS in catkin_package()
> in CMake).
>
> **Test Dependencies** specify only additional dependencies for unit
> tests. They should never duplicate any
> dependencies already mentioned as
> build or run dependencies.
>
> **Build Tool Dependencies** specify build system tools which this package
> needs to build itself. Typically the
> only build tool needed is catkin. In a
> cross-compilation scenario build tool
> dependencies are for the architecture
> on which the compilation is performed.
>
> **Documentation Tool** Dependencies specify documentation tools which this
> package needs to generate
> documentation.

---

Originally posted by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) with karma: 85 on 2019-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1